# IOPS on aws machine decrease after sometime during performance test execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, performance-testing

When I start AWS node, and check average IOPS, it was usually between 3000-4000. But after running my test, when I check the iops in AWS node, I see it keeps on decreasing, impacting the throughput of my perfromance test.
 Not sure if it is expected that iops will keep on dropping after sometime? Can anyone please guide here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOLJW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running GP2 or PIOPs?

If its GP2, it is worth noting that they use burstable credits allowing upto 3000 IOPs. After these credits expire you'll be left with 3 X EBS storage size (in GBs) for IOPs.

So for example, 50GB of storage would be 3 X 50 = 150 IOPs.

This article should help you to further understand: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-burst-balance-metric-for-ec2s-general-purpose-ssd-gp2-volumes/

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through the AWS docs and found this information. Now I have created another node with 1000GB gp2 volume so that base line performance of I/O never goes down below 3000 IOPS